# Inspect sql statement with filled parameters

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql

I have this code and compiler throws this error:

> SqlException: Incorrect syntax near '0'

I can't find the actual SQL statement used by SQL Server to cause this error.

Is there a way to get the SQL statement with parameters for me to reproduce the error and fix it? Or maybe something wrong with my code?

```
void Main()
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable("Task");
    table.Columns.Add("ID");
    table.Columns.Add("Type");
    table.Columns.Add("Worker");    
    table.Columns.Add("CaseID");
    table.Columns.Add("Name");

    DataRow row1 = table.NewRow();
    row1["Type"]="Type1";
    row1["Worker"]="ABCD";
    row1["CaseID"] = "1234567";
    row1["Name"] = "ABC";
    table.Rows.Add( row1 );



    SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    sqlDataAdapter.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand( sqlStatement(),(SqlConnection)Connection);
    sqlDataAdapter.InsertCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    sqlDataAdapter.RowUpdating += new SqlRowUpdatingEventHandler(da_RowUpdating);

    sqlDataAdapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add( "@Type",SqlDbType.VarChar,4, "Type" );
    sqlDataAdapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add( "@Worker",SqlDbType.VarChar,4, "Worker" );
    sqlDataAdapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add( "@CaseID",SqlDbType.VarChar,7, "CaseID" );
    sqlDataAdapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add( "@Name",SqlDbType.VarChar,50, "Name" );

    sqlDataAdapter.Update( table );
}

static void da_RowUpdating(object sender, SqlRowUpdatingEventArgs e)
{
  Console.WriteLine("\nRow Updating...");
  Console.WriteLine("Command text: \n{0}", e.Command.CommandText);
  Console.WriteLine("\nParameters:");
  foreach (SqlParameter p in e.Command.Parameters)
  {
      Console.WriteLine("\t{0} - {1}", p.ParameterName, p.Value);
  }
}
string sqlStatement()
{
    return @"EXECUTE sp_executesql
    N'INSERT  INTO Task
            (
                Type,
              CaseID,
              Worker,
              Name
            )
    VALUES  (
@Type,
              @CaseID,
              @Worker,
              @Name
            );
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS ID',
N'
     @Type varchar(7),
    @CaseID CHAR(7),
    @Worker CHAR(6),
    @Name VARCHAR(50)
    ',{0},{1},{2},{3}";
}
```

Comment: On which line does it throw the exception? Is it really thrown by the compiler? This appears to be runtime error...

Comment: why not replace that `Parameters.Add` Method with `Parameters.AddWithValue` method and let the database handle the determination of the datatype I would also create a Stored procedure to handle the Sql Insert and clean up your code a bit to make it more readable even for yourself

Comment: You can use SQL Server Profiler on the server side to see exactly what SQL statements get executed. But the SQL statements are **NOT** (as many dev expects) "expanded"; e.g. parameter values are **NOT** inserted into the actual SQL - the SQL statement is sent to SQL Server with the parameters in place - so you really won't see a big difference between the SQL statement in your C# code and on the SQL Server side

Comment: the exception throws at sqlDataAdapter.Update( table );

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the `{0},{1},{2},{3}` part of the sql statement with

```
@Type=@Type, @CaseID=@CaseID, @Worker=@Worker, @Name=@Name
```

The format of the parameters in the `sqlStatement` method is fit for use of the .net `string.Format` method, but what you need is a format fit for the SQL Parameter mapping for [sp_executeSql](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx).

---

EDIT: If you cannot modify the `sqlStatement`, you can feed it to the `string.Format` method with the required arguments. My guess is that already exists somewhere in the code, if it's already used. Anyway, it should be something like:

```
string statement = string.Format(sqlStatement(), "@Type=@Type", "@CaseID=@CaseID", "@Worker=@Worker", "@Name=@Name");
sqlDataAdapter.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand(statement,(SqlConnection)Connection);
```

Comment: the sql statement is used by many other places and I can't modify it.

Comment: I use the way you provided give me error: Too many characters in character literal

Comment: sorry, typo (had ' instead of ")

Comment: I have tried double quotes too, or single quotes inside the double quotes. Nothing works. still give me the same error message.

Comment: turns out I was missing something. That's my fault. Your solution does work. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Without comment on your specific code - in general, the 100% effective way to see what SQL is actually being executed is to capture it using SQL Profiler.  You would want to capture the SQL:BatchStarting event in profiler to see the statement and parameters that are actually being passed to the server by your code.

See: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091(v=sql.120).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091%28v=sql.120%29.aspx)

Comment: I have checked SQL profiler when I run the code and it does not show in the profiler. Is it because it's compilation error so that the sql server doesn't even run it?

Comment: Hmm.. I was under the impression that the BatchStarted event would still occur - sorry for the misdirection!